# Web API routing actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

The goal is to allow these four endpoints:

```
POST    v1/invoices<br/>
POST    v1/invoices/12345<br/>
POST    v1/invoices/12345/attachment<br/>
POST    v1/invoices/12345/image
```

Routing entries:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "InvoiceAttachments",
        routeTemplate: "v1/invoices/{id}/attachments",
        defaults: new { controller = "invoices", action = "PostAttachment" }
    );

routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "InvoiceImages",
        routeTemplate: "v1/invoices/{id}/images",
        defaults: new { controller = "invoices", action = "PostImage" }
    );
```

These are my four function definitions in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("PostAttachment")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostAttachment(int id)

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("PostImage")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostImage(int id)

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id)    

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
```

Yet when I post an invoice using the first URI, the route that gets recognized is the attachments route. How do i have endpoints with different sections after the ID variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it!

Route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "InvoiceStuff",
        routeTemplate: "v1/invoices/{id}/{*action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "invoices", action = "" }
    );
```

Function definitions:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Attachments")]
public HttpResponseMessage Attachments([FromUri]int id)

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Images")]
public HttpResponseMessage Images([FromUri]int id)

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post()

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]int id)
```

Works perfectly. Note that in the route I specified a default action of "" because of a defect in webAPI routing with wildcards. Had i not done the default, a null reference exception would have been thrown. More information on the defect can be found here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/718 - slated to be fixed in ASP.NET v5.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you must have another route defined, because the first URI should not be matching the InvoiceAttachments route, because it does not have "/attachments" on the end

Answer (score 0):

Try having a single route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "DefaultAction"  }
);
```

Then decorate functions like

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("DefaultAction")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post()


[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostImage(int id)
```

Comment: That doesn't work for when I do /invoices/12345, it goes to the default action with no id parameter being passed in. :/

Comment: @NiX - have you tried changing the above DefaultAction to accept int id argument ? `Post(int id)` - otherwise you won't ever get an id passed in...

Comment: Yeah and i just realized i forgot one of the desired endpoints: 

POST /v1/invoices

so i need a post() and a post(int id)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using constraints rather than defaults?

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "InvoiceAttachments",
        routeTemplate: "v1/invoices/{id}/attachments",
        defaults: new { controller = "invoices" },
        constraints: new { action = "PostAttachment" } 
    );

routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "InvoiceImages",
        routeTemplate: "v1/invoices/{id}/images",
        defaults: new { controller = "invoices" },
        constraints: new { action = "PostImage" } 
    );

routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Default",
        routeTemplate: "v1/invoices/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "invoices" }
    );
```

**UPDATE:**

You could probably sort of hack it by making the action a url part:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "InvoiceAttachments",
        routeTemplate: "v1/invoices/{id}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "invoices" },
        constraints: new {action = "attachments|images"}
    );

routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "default",
            routeTemplate: "v1/invoices/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "invoices", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new {action = "attachments|images"}
        );
```

and the controller methods:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("attachments")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostAttachment(int id)

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("images")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostImage(int id)

public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id)

public HttpResponseMessage Post()
```

Comment: Tried that and get this exception: "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nSystem.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage PostAttachment(Int32) on type Controllers.Api.InvoicesController\r\nSystem.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Post(Int32) on type Controllers.Api.InvoicesController",